# How to apply CSS stylesheet into vue app properly?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Im working on a google chrome extention using vue as framework. I got the app mounted and the title displays on the page. However, im having issues adding the styling to a div. This is my app code:

```
  <template>
  <div class="sdk-ts-container">
    <h1>DFS Support Extension</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SdkToolboxRoot'
}
</script>
<style>
.sdk-ts-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 700px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  float: right;
}
</style>
```

After reloading the page, no styling changes appear, just the plain title. I tried adding the same styling using chrome developer tool and it works, so i think the css class is correct but something with vue is preventing it to show. Can anyone advise me what im missing? Thank you

Comment: Hi, Try using `<style scoped>` in the file.

Comment: I tried this and its still doesn't apply css. Also tried putting the CSS into a different file and then using import to add the css, still doesnt work.

Comment: I think your code is correct. You can wrap the div with class in another div and then see what happens.

Comment: It worked great when I pasted your code in the Vue playground https://sfc.vuejs.org/

Comment: @YashMaheshwari i tried wrapping my div container with another div, still Doenst work and yes the code looks correct to me as well. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors or warnings?

Comment: No errors, unfortunately.